# Quiet installation in "advanced updater \ installer"

Tags: installation, windows-installer, advanced-installer

I'm trying to do automatic update in quiet mode. To do this, I write the command line:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\progsoft\prog> prog.exe /silentall
```

But the program is not updated. When I do so

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\progsoft\prog> prog.exe /silentall -nofreqcheck
```

That window will appear with the opportunity to install the update. But this is not a quiet setting. I might ask something wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Is prog.exe a metaphore? I don't understand the question at all.

Comment: Advanced Installer provides a stub called "updater.exe" which the users can integrate in their applications, and configure using an attached INI file found next to it, to handle automatic updates for their applications. The stub can be renamed as the users want to, in this case it was called "prog.exe".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first command the update is not performed because the frequency check period has not passed, so the updater exits immediately.

The second command is correct too, and the UI should not be visible. In this case the updater should be visible only as a tray icon, and only if you click on that icon it will present the full UI. Did you clicked that icon or has the updater appeared from the beginning with full UI?

When receiving the "/silentall" parameter the updater is automatically launched with full UI, but instantly minimized to the tray. It may be a problem on your machine that prevented the minimization process and the updater remained running with full UI.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!But what if I want to call the update in silent mode? In my program uses a timer that starts the process every 5 minutes to check for updates. Ie if there are no updates, he would have nothing to show. In the system tray icons do not ... There's only when I call to-nofreqcheck but there is no quiet setting.

Comment: "/silentall -nofreqcheck" should work silently, have you tried it on other machines? Also, 5 minutes is a little too often I would say. Normally the updater is scheduled to check once a day or when the application is launched.